# Use a variable in another required file

Tags: php

I would like to create a multiple language website but I have a problem!
I will explain it to you with an example:
**lang-en.php**

```
<?php
  $lang = [];
  $lang['hello'] = "Wellcome $userName to our website!";
 ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $useName = "Amir";
  require_once("lang-en.php");
  echo $lang['hello'];
 ?>
```

Now, I would like to see this output in my page:

> Welcome Amir to our website!

How can i do this?

Comment: `Welcome '$useName' to our website`

Comment: Are you looking for [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Or `str_replace`.

Comment: Two problems you have, first your array initialization. which you corrected just now. second, your userName variable has to be the same as in lang file. I wrote an answer on how you can display the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be smart to make it a bit more complicated, to look to the future. If you remove the implementation part to a separate class, you can have your actual usage and the implementation of the translation separate. If you plan to use `gettext` (po/mo files) later, you can switch easier.

A simple, but untested, example would be

```
class translate{

    private $translations = [
          'hello' => "Wellcome %s to our website!",
    ]

    public function trans($key, $value)
    {
        return sprintf($this->translations[$key], $value);
    }
}
```

Mind you, this is a quick example, and probably needs some work -> for instance, it presumes always a single variable, etc etc. But the idea is that you create  class with an internal implementation, and a function that you call. If you can keep the function call's footprint the same, you can change the working of your translation system!

You'll call this like so

```
$trans = new Translate();
echo $trans->trans('hello', 'Amir');
```

(again, I typed this in the answer box, no check for syntax, testing etc has been done, so this is probably not a copy-paste ready class, but it is about the idea)

edit: as requested, a bit more example. Again, not tested, probably some syntax errors etc, but to help you with the idea:

```
class translate{

    private $translations = [
          'hello' => array('test' =>"Welcome %s to our website!", 'vars' => 1),
          'greet' => array('test' =>"I'd like to say $s to %s ", 'vars' => 2),
    ]

    public function trans($key, array $values)
    {
        // no translation
        if(!isset($this->translations[$key])){
            return false; // or exception if you want
        }
        // translation needs more (or less) variables
        if($this->translations[$key][vars] !== count($values)){
            return false; // or exception if you want        
        }

        // note: now using vsprintf
        return vsprintf($this->translations[$key], $values);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i do it for more than variable? for example a text with this text: "Hello [Amir] welcome to our website" And another text with this text "Hey [Amir]! are sure you need to run [Delete] action for this post?". (Note: [variable])

Comment: Well, the issue is, I think, error handling. You should, if doing it right, have something that knows if you can even fullfill the request to the function, and otherwise act on the problem. But you can have the values as an array, or something like that. I can add a bit, but in the end you need to take home the way-of-thinking, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Amir Agha,

When you call another .php file by `include` or `require` php acts as if the contents of the included file is inserted in the same line and the same scope (except for classes and functions) so your code in the view of php interpreter looks like this:

```
<?php
  $userName = "Amir";
  $lang = [];
  $lang['hello'] = "Wellcome $userName to our website!";
  echo $lang['hello'];
 ?>
```

So this code must display:

Wellcome Amir to our website!

But why it doesn't work? Simply because you wrote `$useName` instead of `$userName` in your index.php file.

p.s.: Other answers made it very complicated. only change `$useName` to `$userName`

Comment: Kheyli mamnoonam azetoon, this is good but i need include from another file!

Comment: I told it as an example not a solution.
You must change `$useName` to `$userName` in your `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function one in lang-en.php

```
<?php 
function lang($username)
{       
$lang['hello'] = $username;   
echo $lang['hello'];        
}  
?>
```

In index.php call that function

```
<?php
require_once("lang-en.php");
lang('arun');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you nearly had it
langen.php

```
<?php

   //declare array
   $lang = array();
   $templang['hello1'] = "Wellcome ";
   $templang['hello2'] = " to our website!";   
   //add new item in array
   array_push($lang,$templang);

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
   $useName = "Amir";
   require_once("langen.php");
   //it is first entry of array row so [0] is 0
   echo $lang[0]['hello1'];
   echo $userName;
   echo $lang[0]['hello2'];
   //out is welcome amir to our website
?>
```

this is a easy way too see how to pass variables a little long way but i didn't want to combine so that you can see how it works you can also do some reading about sessions for passing variables between pages that is not included